# Want to refer to variable in the outer function's scope from an inner function being returned

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a simple program that gets 2 functions(a and k) and one integer value(b), then it gets the formal parameter in the two functions(a and k) which is "x" and applies a condition x < b then based on the condition makes a function call, either a or b. But when I run the program it gives an error that x is not defined in the global frame. I want it to get "x" from the formal parameter assigned to the functions a and b and then get the condition based on that.

Here's my code

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def piecewise(a, k, b):
    if x<b:
        return a
    else:
        return k
mak = piecewise(increment,square ,3 )
print(mak(1))
```

Comment: your third method cannot use x because it is not a parameter for the method.

Comment: Yes I know the problem but I can't figure out how to fix this. I want "x" to be equal to mak, making mak(x)

Comment: What is a "function call variable" supposed to be? Can you rephrase your question to use accurate terminology?

Comment: ...I understand that you're storing a function in a variable, and later calling it, but that's a *function* that you're storing, not a *function call*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
def piecewise(a, k, b):
    def f(x):
        if x < b:
            return a(x)
        else:
            return k(x)
    return f
```

However, I am not sure if it is a good practice. So, I leave my answer here to see the comments and learn if there is any problem with it.

Comment: This would seem like a relatively common pattern to me. I posted the same implementation in my deleted answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ah sorry I know it was a a very simple solution but I'm just not used to python

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This answer is practically the same, was submitted earlier, and the user deserves the rep.

Comment: Ahh; I missed the time difference.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I thought it might not be a good coding practice because the behavior of the returning function is not clear from the context at the time we call it. So, it might confuse the next user of the code. But, now that I know it is a common pattern, I will use it.